# wget recursive returns BAD REQUEST

Tags: wget

I've tried downloading files from different subdirs using wget

```
wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off --auth-no-challenge --user=myusr --ask-password https://myexdomain.com/dir/subdir/
```

and it works without any problems.

When I however, make the wget call to one directory-level up

```
wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off --auth-no-challenge --user=myusr --ask-password https://myexdomain.com/dir/
```

wget returns   400: BAD REQUEST

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP error 400 is fairly generic and usually related to the formatting of the client request.  Without you providing the actual websites in question for us to test, it's a bit difficult to guess.  However, here are a few guesses:

- Does it work fine on plain http but not on https?  If so, it may be related to a security policy.
- Are you using a firewall, router, or resident antivirus that inspects packets?  If so, it may be changing the packet structure rendering it invalid.  If you're on a bigger network, is there such a device between you and the host in question (a tracert would help you figure that out).
- Do you have access to this host server?  If so, can you create new directories and test the exact conditions under which it fails?  Is it always at the one-directory-below-root level?
- You're excluding robots, which can be fine sometimes, but can also trigger different responses from servers depending on context.  Have you tested without the robots exclusion?
- Have you tried with a different user-agent?  Some servers respond differently to wget user-agents.  Can you access these files in a web-browser?  Using curl?  Or with a different user-agent specified with --user-agent in your wget command?

If none of this works, let us know the results of additional testing.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions as far as possible, without success.
It's a JIRA server on atlassian. The problem might be that no one is allowed to list subdirectories under /dir , but if one knows the /subdir then one can download files from it.
Since this is not a JIRA forum, I guess my question is wether there's something wrong with my wget command or not? (Given your inputs on robots and user-agent)

Comment: Since there are no subdirs below /subdir I've never really successfully tried wget recursively through subdirs, only recursive on files within a directory.

Comment: Ah, "no one is allowed to list subdirectories under /dir".  That's it.  If listing isn't permitted, `wget` has no way of seeing the files.  It will send a listing request and get back error 400.

Easy way to test.  Remove `-r -nd --no-parent` and try downloading an actual /file/ below dir.  One that you know the name of.  If you can do it, then it's the listing restriction.

Comment: Must be it! Sadly I don't know the name of any files there. However, trying that technique on other folders seem to further indicate that it's a listing permission issue.
Thanks @Mekki